# Компьютер не видит микрофона и наушников

Tags: windows, ubuntu, аудио, dual-boot

Поставил Windows 10, была Windows 7. Пропал звук, смотрю в реалтек там нет подключенных устройств, переподключаю, но всё равно не видит. Откатываю его, ставится дефолтный, но он тоже не видит, хотя когда захожу с Ubuntu то всё окей.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Можно попробовать скачать драйвера для Win10 и переустановить их.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Если комп фирменный типа Asus, Aser и прочие, то на сайте фирмы обычно лежат драйвера для разных ОС. Если комп самосборный, то надо искать драйвера на сайте производителя звуковой платы или на сайте производителя материнки, если звук интегрированный.

Comment: Тут нагуглил что есть 2 типа дров от Realtek, первый тип для старых звуковых карт это AC97, второй для новых это HDA, возможно у меня стояла AC97, а я поставил HDA и всё стало плохо, сейчас переустанавливаю на АС97, не знаю поможет ли мне, но вдруг кому-то полезно будет

Comment: у меня стояла HDA версия, не помогло(

Comment: А в списке оборудования что пишет? По мнению win10 драйвер нормально установлен?

Comment: В принципе винда должна сказать, что драйвер не подходит для данного оборудования. И тогда винда даже ставить драйвер откажется.

Comment: А он вообще не ставился, просто вылетал. А то что стоял HDA я понял по загруженному ранее файлу, когда ставил Win7. В списке оборудования только цифровое аудио, ни наушников, ни микро нету. Пытался через диспетчер обновлять, но пишет что уже последняя версия и всё хорошо. Уже даже автоматический поиск неполадок запускал, у него как всегда всё окей

Comment: лан, придется походу винду менять

Comment: Смена винды не помогла, подозреваю что дело в настройках биоса, я их сбрасывал, мож там чего важного стояло

Comment: Снес всё, поставил заново Ubuntu 18.04
Звук пропал и тут, не помогают никакие утилиты

Comment: В общем купил внешнюю звуковую карту за 5$ и она норм заменяет встроенную, больше не парюсь